# linux disassembler

Tags: linux, assembly, disassembly

how can I write just a simple disassembler for linux from scratches?
Are there any libs to use? I need something that "just works".

Comment: What architecture(s) are you targeting, as this is significantly more relevent than the OS.

Comment: Sorry I've omitted which architecture, I'm tryng disassembling under x86

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to understand the [ELF file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) first. Then, you can start processing the various sections of code according to the opcodes of your architecture.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of writing one, try [Objdump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objdump).

Based on your comment, and your desire to implement from scratch, I take it this is a school project.  You could get the source for objdump and see what libraries and techniques it uses.
The [BFD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_File_Descriptor_library) library might be of use.

Comment: I't not the aim of my project, i usually use any kind of debugger and disassembler.

Answer (score 1):

You can use libbfd and libopcodes, which are libraries distributed as part of binutils.

http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/

As an example of the power of these libraries, check out the Online Disassembler (ODA).

http://www.onlinedisassembler.com

ODA supports a myriad of architectures and provides a basic feature set. You can enter binary data in the Live View and watch the disassembly appear as you type, or you can upload a file to disassemble. A nice feature of this site is that you can share the link to the disassembly with others.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the code of [ERESI](http://www.eresi-project.org/)

> The ERESI Reverse Engineering Software Interface is a multi-architecture binary analysis framework with a tailored domain specific language for reverse engineering and program manipulation.